# Python, matrizes/vetores e dicionários

Tags: python

Olá, sou novo no python e não sei como se deve ser feito:

1) tenho uma matriz 2x6 gerada por números aleatorios, por exemplo:

```
matriz = [11, 4,  50, 8,  9,  78]
         [10, 33, 44, 57, 80, 90]
```

O que preciso fazer é o seguinte: 
        ao sortear um valor no intervalo da linha 2 [10, 33, 44 ...] devo retornar o seu respectivo valor da linha 1, por exemplo caso o numero sorteado
    for 85, devo retornar o valor 9 da linha 1. Caso tenha saído o valor 38 no sorteio, devo retornar o valor 4 da linha 1.

valor de 10 a 32 da segunda linha corresponde ao valor 11 da linha 1
valor de 33 a 43 da segunda linha corresponde ao valor 4 da linha 1 e assim sucessivamente, porém a matriz é gerada pode ser de 2x10, 2x30 e etc

Código:

```
import random

Pessoa = random.sample(range(1,25),10)
Nota   = random.sample(range(1,25),10)

Pessoa.sort()
Nota.sort()
tmp = sum(Nota)

# sorteando um valor
n_escolhido=random.randrange(1,tmp)

print('Numero sorteado: ', n_escolhido)
```

Fiz utilizando lista ao invés de matriz mas parei neste ponto pois não consigo fazer equivalência da lista de pessoa com os intervalos das notas.

Comment: A intenção do primeiro é ser código mesmo? É erro de sintaxe. E tem algum problema que está tendo no seu código? cadê ele?

Comment: Coloque o código que você esta tentando executar, os outros membros iram te ajudar a resolver e não resolver pra você.

Comment: Entendi o exercício, onde tu está travando? Em qual parte está dando erro? Adiciona o código que tu tentou fazer na pergunta para te ajudarmos

Comment: Coloquei o que fiz até o momento, ainda não consegui descobrir uma forma de verificar os intervalos, estou dando uma olhada em dicionarios...

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando os dados do seu é exemplo pode ser simples, lembrando que esse código só vai funcionar se os valores da segunda linha da matriz estiverem em ordem crescente.

Utilizei `Numpy` para criar um array `2x6` ( o mesmo array do seu exemplo), a lógica do algoritmo é simples, crie um loop e compare a posição da coluna `atual` da linha `2` da matriz e a posição da coluna `atual+1`, se o seu número estiver entre os dois valores imprima o valor da coluna correspondente da linha `1`

o Código

```
import numpy as np

#criando array do exemplo
matriz = np.array([[11, 4,  50, 8,  9,  78],[10, 33, 44, 57, 80, 90]])

#entre 10 e 32 = 11
#entre 33 e 43 = 4
#entre 44 e 56 = 50
#entre 57 e 79 = 8
#entre 80 e 89 = 9
#entre 90 e inf = 78

#numero para testar o algoritmo ou pegar número randômico entre 10 e 90
numero=68
numero=np.random.randint(10,90)

#imprime qual número estamos usando
print(numero)

#anda na segunda linha da matriz comparando a posição atual com a próxima posição
for i in range(0, matriz[1:,].shape[1]-1):
    if (numero >= matriz[1,i]) and (numero < matriz[1,i+1]):
        print(matriz[0,i])

#o ultimo índice foi deixado de fora no loop, comparar agora        
if numero >= matriz[1,i+1]:
    print(matriz[0,i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Com o número sorteado, presente na segunda linha da matriz

```
numero_sorteado = 90 # Exemplo
```

Você vai achar o índice desse número na linha em que ele está presente

```
index_numero_sorteado = matriz[1].index(numero_sorteado)
```

Com esse número é só acessar a primeira linha da matriz e retornar o valor correspondente

```
numero_correspondente = matriz[0][index_numero_sorteado]
```

Comment: Mas e se o valor sorteado for 68, qual indice ele irá retornar?

Comment: Nesse caso 68 não está na segunda linha da matriz, então o exemplo que dei vai dar erro, aí nesse caso é necessário verificar se o número sorteado realmente está na segunda linha.